# Core Data NSDocument App- Open PDF, Save as Bundle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf, core-data, appkit

I'm working on an app that needs to be able to open a PDF document and then save as a bundle containing this PDF and the core data object graph.  The app should also open the custom bundle.

Any pointers on where to start?

Thanks

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if I should be using NSDocument or NSPersistentDocument here. I developed the app originally without Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say these two sources:

- [Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1)

You certainly can use NSPersistentDocument. When you create your data model, you could create a root document object with a data object and external storage to store the PDF.

Or, use NSDocument, and handle the bundle loading and Core Data stack yourself.